# Are there any hidden consequences of equipping the Halo Device?

Tags: warhammer-40k-rogue-trader

On the Ice World Abondend Palace in Mundus Nullius, after killing a local boss you can find a peculiar and very powerful trinket called "Halo Device"

[image]

However, there is a warning that this item cannot be removed once equipped and some of your companions try to dissuade you from equipping it.

Are there any hidden consequences of equipping this device? Does it swing you to the heretical path somehow? According to the Warhammer Wiki, the [Halo Devices](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Halo_Devices) are very dangerous, although not connected to Chaos (which suggests that there are things stranger even than the Dark Gods or C'Tan)